# Helios Eclipse java debugger on Windows is very slow to highlight source code

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, debugging, performance

I have Eclipse Helios SR1 installed on Windows XP.  I am writing/debugging Java code using JDK 1.6.

When I debug and I hit a breakpoint, Eclipse is fast to show me the stacktrace.  (See #1 in attached image.)

However, the source code line highlight (light green, see #2 in attached image) is very slow to appear.  Oddly, when I first installed Eclipse, this was very fast.  Now it is very slow.  It takes about 15 seconds to highlight as light green.

Any ideas what is wrong with my Eclipse install/config?

FYI: Very fast processor + 4GB of RAM.  Plenty of disk space.  I have tried a "Hello, World" test Java project.  Just a few lines of code... still the same issue when hitting a vanilla breakpoint.

[image]

Comment: Did you try with an optimized `eclipse.ini`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659 , and see if the issue persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: Create a new workspace.

I did it and now my debugger is super-fast again.

Answer (score 2):

According to [running-a-program-in-debug-mode-is-incredible-slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591187/running-a-program-in-debug-mode-is-incredible-slow) I succeeded with running

> eclipse -clean

(test this before you setup a new workspace)

Answer (score 0):

This is surely not an Eclipse problem. If it is highlighting, means its working.

There must be something wrong with the Windows. More RAM does not mean necessarily fast processing. Check Task Manager, and try to monitor processes, especially the java one. There can be multiple 
java processes, kill unnecessary ones.

If the laptop using some sort of disk encryption, then this is surely possible.

If your anti-virus is hogging the CPU, quite possible.

Comment: actually i've noticed this recently on latest update to helios on ubuntu as well.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out Eclipse just because it appears to be working.

Comment: In my case the funny thing is that once stepping over a line, processing carries on asynchronously in other threads triggered by that step very quickly and with good performance. It appears to just be the highlighting and debugging routines in Eclipse taking 3-30s to move to the next line for the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

Or else you can do one more thing is that everyday you can manually clean your project and you can also set the console limit to unlimited.