# File I/O is incredibly slow in Eclipse debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I've often found the debug mode of Eclipse useful over relying on print statements or logging.  However, I've found that the debug mode's performance seems to be *particularly* sensitive to file I/O.  Loading a file can be **way** slower (taking ~25 times as long), and since my workflow requires loading a rather large file before I get to anything interesting, this is particularly inconvenient for me.

Is there any sensible workaround for this issue?  I don't actually need the debugging during the file loading part, so is there perhaps a way to only jump into debug mode at a certain point in the process?

Note that, unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4591187/387852), I do not believe this is a problem with the state of my workspace.

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into a running application with eclipse's remote debuging feature. You have to start your app with some parameters:

`java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y  suspend=y -jar yourapp.jar`

Then in your debug configuration choose Remote Java Application using port 8001.

More detailed with pics [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you're doing IO in a slow way (reading in small pieces), and debugging is just amplifying that, since there's overhead for every function call.

NetBeans has a way to specify which functions to profile, so I'd look for a similar option in Eclipse, and then tell it not to profile anything in the `java.*` namespace, or any of your IO specific code if that doesn't help.

I'd also make sure you're reading your file in a fast way (using buffered input streams, not using `Scanner`, etc.). There may also be things in [NIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) that could help, but I'm not that familiar with it.

Comment: This doesn't really help me.  The IO's performance is fine when not debugging, and I'm not interested in micro-optimizing it now as it's good enough and I have more important concerns.  I'm not using NetBeans, and obviously if I could find such an option in Eclipse then I wouldn't have asked this question.