# Program execution in Eclipse is very slow when compared to command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a Java program which reads encrypted files from local system and does some processing. Actually I have 20 files to read so I have used threading mechanism to speed up the program execution.

When I run the program in Eclipse it takes more than 30 minutes to complete the execution, whereas if I make a runnable jar and execute the program using command prompt, it takes less than a minute.

Why does running programs in Eclipse take more time than running them in command prompt?

Comment: Do you by any chance print a lot to the `System.out`? Because that would immediately explain your observation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes I used the System.out I print say 5-10k times depending on the program logic.Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, it is. Remove the printout and you'll see an immediate speedup. Eclipse's Console view is dramatically slower than `stdout` at the command line.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just FYI if you want to run an eclipse program from command line you can cd to the `bin/` directory of your eclipse project and run `java package.path.Classname` at any time.  Building an executable jar isn't necessary.

Comment: @dimo414 And what about the classpath?

Comment: If everything's in the project, it should work just fine.  If you've got a complex build setup, it may not work.  Was just a suggestion, since that's what I do from time to time.

Comment: linking possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591187/running-a-program-in-debug-mode-is-incredible-slow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eclipse's Console view that captures `System.out` is notoriously slow compared to the regular `stdout` of the command line. Whenever there is a lot of printing happening in the program, it is to be expected that the program will run significantly slower from Eclipse.

But anyway, unless you are writing a program designed to integrate with other programs via Unix pipes, you should minimize the printing as it will kill performance even at the command line.

Comment: Yes, commenting System.out has speed-up the process of execution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are some typical mistakes:

- Maybe you are executing your program in Debug mode.

  Try to use Run (play symbol inside a green circle) instead of Debug (a green bug)
- Maybe you are executing your program with a different JVM

  Take a look in `Project Properties->Java compiler`, `Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler` and `Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs`
- The output and input interactions with Java Console of Eclipse JDT differ on performance than standard console.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you use the Run action in Eclipse, and not Debug, as the latter really has measurable difference, especially if you use conditional breakpoints.

However, I remember having less significant differences arising from the use of the Debug.

Comment: I am using the Run action only and not using debug mechanism. Still i see huge delay to process compared to command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I have just did an experiment for you and did not saw so significant difference.
I created class that calculates `sin()` `100000000` times. 
This program ran ~15 seconds under eclipse and ~14 seconds via command prompt.

So, here are the reasons for slowness in your system I can see at the top of my head:

1. Be sure that you are not running under debug. Use Run option, not Debug.
2. Be sure that you do not have some coverage/monitoring developers tools on under eclipse. For example YourKit, Emma etc.
3. Be sure that your program does not produce significant prints to the console.
4. Check that you have enough heap memory when running under eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Changing jdk 6 to jdk 7 worked perfectly for me. 
Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs