# OpenJDK platform binary has stopped working in eclipse while debugging JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, javafx, breakpoints

Every time I try to debug a javaFx application I receive this error `OpenJDK platform binary has stopped working`. Which is the problem? The position of breakpoints are bad or there are many parts of the code, e.g. event handler,  that can't be debugged?

**EDIT**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

    login();

}

public void login() {
    
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Google");
    
    WebView root = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine = root.getEngine();
    
    engine.load("https://www.google.com");
    
    engine.setOnStatusChanged(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
        public void handle(WebEvent<String> event) {
            
            System.out.println("here");
            
        }
    });
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    
}
```

The stage that appears is totally white and doesn't work. When the exit button of windows is clicked appear the error `OpenJDK platform binary has stopped working`

Comment: If you mean your JavaFX application claims it has "stopped working", then that is to be expected when the _JavaFX Application Thread_ is suspended at a breakpoint (or indirectly suspended by a breakpoint configured to suspend all threads when one reaches it). As you step through the code things will update. If you resume execution things should return to normal.

Comment: If I continue to skip breakpoints, at the end of the code I receive this error: An internal error occurred during: "Debug child count update".
java.lang.IllegalStateException.
And my stage appears completely white.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose there could be a problem caused by suspending threads used by JavaFX, but I don't remember ever encountering such a problem myself. Though I've always used IntelliJ over Eclipse. Is  it possible to provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Deleting all breakpoints helped (Run/Remove all breakpoints), cmp
[Running a program in Debug mode is incredible slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591187/running-a-program-in-debug-mode-is-incredible-slow)